# log4net different folder based on cmdline data

Tags: log4net

Let's say I have an app that accepts a commandline argument of the state code. Each state has it's own job so the app itself can be running many times at the same time but only ever once per state at a time. I want to use this commandline argument to create/write to a folder with it's same value for logging so that they aren't tripping over each other. So at the end I'd have:

```
logfiles/WI/logfile.log
logfiles/MN/logfile.log
logfiles/MI/logfile.log
```

Where WI, MN, MI were commandline arguments to the 1 app.

What I currently tried to do was use the formatting of string.Format() in the app.config and in code loop over and use that cmdline value to create the log folder by state name.

```
<param name="File" value="./logfiles/{0}/logfile.txt" />

public static void SetupLogFileVendorPath(string state)
        {
            foreach (var fileAppender in LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().OfType<FileAppender>())
            {
                // apply transformation to the filename
                fileAppender.File = string.Format(fileAppender.File, state);

                // notify the logging subsystem of the configuration change
                fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
```

This sort of works as it does create the state folder and the log file in it, but it also creates a folder named:

```
logfiles/{0}/logfile.txt
```

Because it does this if 2 instances happen to run at the same exact time it could create an issue as both try to write to this file under {0} which they all do initially once the line LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders() is called. They just put header/footer but it does write to this one central place which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there any way to get the structure I'm looking for while avoiding this {0} with the way I'm doing it with string.Format()

Comment: Sounds like you are activating your logging before calling SetupLogFileVendorPath.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the state code commandline argument to a [Log4net context property](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string stateCode = args[0];
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["stateCode"] = stateCode;    

    // ...
}
```

Include this context property in the output file path of your `(Rolling)FileAppender` configuration via `%property{stateCode}`.

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logfiles\%property{stateCode}\logfile.log" />

    <!-- More settings here -->
</parameters>
```

Doing so will create a subfolder with the name of the passed commandline argument.